# How to make Kate remember to always show line numbers?

Tags: linux, kde, kate

When I open Kate editor, it doesn't show the line numbers by default. Then I need to go to the **`View`** menu and enable the **`Show Line Numbers`** option (or press F11) every time I need to have line numbers shown.
How to make Kate remember to always show line numbers?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To make Kate permanently showing the line numbers:

1. Open the `Settings` -> `Configure Kate…`.
2. Go to the `Editor Component` -> `Appearance`.
3. Select the `Borders` tab.
4. Tick the `Show line numbers` check box.
5. Click `Apply`
6. Click `OK`
   [image]